# JS indexedDB onupgradeneeded takes too long to execute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, indexeddb

Hello I have a React APP which is suited for canvas drawing. User can draw on canvases which are stored in notebooks, in manner that one canvas is one A4 page. I use IndexedDb to store these notebooks. Each notebook is an object store inside a database. When the user creates new notebook the following code is executed:

```js
export function createNotebook(name, version) {
    console.log(version);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const dbName = localStorage.getItem("user");
        const request = indexedDB.open(dbName, version);

        request.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
            const db = event.target.result;

            if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains(name)) {
                db.createObjectStore(name, { autoIncrement: true });
                console.log("Object store created for notebook:", name);
            }
        };

        request.onerror = function (event) {
            reject("Error opening/creating the database: " + event.target.error);
        };

        request.onsuccess = function () {
            resolve();
        };
    });
}
```

This code is called from react component: here are lines where the method is called:

```js
export function Body(props) {

    let notebookNames = [];
    if (localStorage.getItem("notebookNames")) {
        notebookNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notebookNames"));
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem("notebookNames", JSON.stringify(notebookNames));
    }
    function updateNotebookNames(name) {
        if (!notebookNames.some((notebook) => notebook.notebookName === name)) {
            console.log("Starting creation");
            notebookNames.push({
                username: localStorage.getItem("user"),
                notebookName: name,
            });
            localStorage.setItem("notebookNames", JSON.stringify(notebookNames));

            console.log("Notebooks names set");

            setIsLoading(true);
            let version = notebookNames.length
            if(version > notebookNames.filter((notebook) => notebook.username === localStorage.getItem("user"))){
                version = notebookNames.filter((notebook) => notebook.username === localStorage.getItem("user"))
            }
            createNotebook(notebookName, version + 1)
                .then(() => {
                    console.log("Notebook created successfully");
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error("Error creating notebook:", error);
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    setIsLoading(false);
                });
        }
    }

    const [notebookName, setNotebookName] = useState(
        localStorage.getItem("notebook")
    );
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
    const [newNotebookName, setNewNotebookName] = useState("");
    const inputRef = useRef(null); // Add a useRef for the input element

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isModalOpen) {
            inputRef.current.focus(); 
        }
    }, [isModalOpen]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (notebookName) {
            updateNotebookNames(notebookName);
        }

        setName(notebookName);
    }, [notebookName]);
```

I have spend a lot of time figuring out why the creation of notebook takes so long and i think it is due to onupgradeneeded call. However, i cannot figure out how to fix it. There are situation that it takes up to 60 seconds to finish. Important note is that when I let it be it finishes, but the waiting time is horrible in such application.

Comment: You don't seem to be explicitly closing the connection, so you're waiting for garbage collection to kick in and reclaim the connection object. For example, once the "success" event fires you never actually close the database, e.g. calling `request.result.close()` in the success handler. If you don't close the connection, it willr remain open and block any subsequent upgrades. Avoid this by explicitly closing when done with a connection, or registering a ":versionchange" handler - https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#handling-versionchange

Comment: Also, schema changes are usually coupled with code changes - modifying the database schema by creating a new object store for each piece of user-created data is a poor use of the API. Consider having a single object store representing notebooks, with keys including the name, e.g. `[name, property]`. Then you never need to deal with upgrades until your code changes.